# VisualSVN - unbind solution/project from SVN

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visualsvn

I'm new to Visual Studio 2010 and to VisualSVN.
I've found how to share a project (a solution in fact): right click on the Solution > VisualSVN > Add Solution to Subversion. It works fine.
Now I regret and I'd like to unbind this solution from SVN, and continue working standalone on my project. How do I do that?

Many thanks guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can manually delete the folders .svn or _svn in your solution to unbind the solution from SVN repository

Comment: It worked, thank you Mario. Don't forget to restart Visual Studio.